# how to bring in splines (bs()) into lasso logistic regression (cv.glmnet)

Tags: r, logistic, lasso, splines, glmnet

Assume I have train dataset below, I avoided using `model.matrix()` and instead I used `dummyVars()` because I want dummy variables to represent all levels of my categorical variable. 
Now I am confused where to enter `bs()` function for numerical variables. I want all numerical variables to enter the lasso model like `bs(train_x$a, df=3), bs(train_x$b, df=3)`. In my actualy dataset I have a large number of numerical variables though.
[Spline regression with many features in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373997/spline-regression-with-many-features-in-r) is the only post I found pointing out this problem but the answer there would not work for large number of variables. in fact even for one variable, I would have to change the column names and ...

I would appreciate any hint, example, thoughts on what is the procedure of performing a lasso regression model over variables some of which need spline calculations.

```
train <- data.frame(a = c(1:100),
                      b = c(101:200),
                      c = as.factor(rep(c("tall", "short"), 
                             times=50)),
                      output = as.factor(rep(c("Yes", "No"), 
                             times=50)))

  a   b     c output
1 1 101  tall    Yes
2 2 102 short     No
3 3 103  tall    Yes

dmy <- dummyVars(output~ ., data = train, sep=": ")
train_x <- data.frame(predict(dmy, newdata = train), 
                           check.names = FALSE)
train_y <- ifelse(train$output == "Yes", 1, 0)

  a   b c: short c: tall
1 1 101        0       1
2 2 102        1       0
3 3 103        0       1

cv <- cv.glmnet(train_x, train_y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial")
model <- glmnet(train_x, train_y, alpha = 1, family = "binomial", 
           lambda = cv$lambda.1se)
```