# Using natural spline in glmnet

Tags: r, regression, splines, glmnet

I want to ask if it is possible to include a natural spline(as one predictor) in the lasso model. When I do that in glm model, I can use `ns()` function on the predictor side.
I came across the following post mentioning adding the base function to the X matrix.
[Spline regression with many features in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373997/spline-regression-with-many-features-in-r)

I used the data from this notebook https://www.kaggle.com/code/floser/glm-neural-nets-and-xgboost-for-insurance-pricing/notebook
My code for producing the design matrix is as follows:

```
splined = ns(train.DrivAge, df = 4)
splined_df = as.data.frame(splined)
X = cbind(train,splined_df)
X = X%>% select(-ClaimNb,-Area,-Exposure,-DrivAge)
X = model.matrix(~.,data = X )
set.seed(1)
cv.lasso =cv.glmnet(x = X, 
                    y = train.ClaimNb,
                    weights = train$Exposure,
                    family = "poisson",
                    alpha = 1,
                    nfolds=20)
```

However, I am not convinced that this method will work because if we include the spline base function in X and allow glmnet to estimate the coefficients, the spline may not be continuous as we don't impose the continuity in X. I took a look at the output of the `ns()` function and found that it has knot, degree and intercept the information. I think `ns()` output includes more information than just the base function. Unlike the glm function where we can directly use ns() function(including all the continuous constraints), in glmnet we can only estimate the coefficients based on the truncated cubic base function. The continuous constraint information is lost in beta estimation. That will cause the spline of different pieces not able to connect to each other.
The coefficients I got for the glmnet with ns spline are as follows. I think the coefficients should keep decreasing but the coefficient corresponding to '4' is higher than others.
`1`            4.995433e-01
`2`            2.402127e-01
`3`            3.476267e-01
`4`            1.347808e+00

Could you let me know your thoughts? Is there any way to include natural spline in glmnet?

Comment: I don't see a problem.  Please can you write out what the spline design matrix output from ns will be and why using it as an input will be a problem in glmnet

Comment: Because `glmnet` accepts the model matrix as input, and `R` supports many ways to create model matrices with splines, the short answer is "of course this is possible."  But could you explain what you mean by "we don't impose the continuity in X"?  Splines of any order greater than zero are automatically continuous.  What exactly do you mean by "the base function" and "the continuity constraints"?

Comment: @seanv507  Hello, I updated the post by adding the information you asked for. Could you help take a look when you get a chance? Thanks.

Comment: @whuber Hello, I think the beta we estimated from glmnet corresponding to different truncated power basis(1 4.995433e-01 2 2.402127e-01 3 3.476267e-01 4 1.347808e+00 in the post above)may affect the continuity. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think so, because that's not how splines work.  Each element of the spline basis is continuous, guaranteeing that any linear combination is continuous.

Comment: Make sense, thanks.